# phpMyAdmin/MySQL issues

Tags: mysql, centos

I recently installed phpMyAdmin with MySQL, it works fine, allows the root to login via the website, but when I attempt to create users and give assign them to a database, it gives me the error "#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server". This server is running on CentOS 5.8.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the credentials in the phpMyAdmin configuration are correct and that it is pointed at the correct server.  You may also check your mysql logs (possibly in the system logger but generally `/var/log/mysql/mysqld.err` and `/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log`) to see what happens when you try to do anything in phpMyAdmin.

Remember that phpMyAdmin's login is separate from the mysql login.

Comment: I deleted the mysqld.log and then tried to login again, nothing changed, still getting #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Comment: I didn't mean that deleting the logs would help; I meant that more information on the error would be contained in them.